# Landlord Asking Me to Pay for Weather Damage

Tags: tenant, michigan

I live in an old building in Kalamazoo, Mi and a few weeks ago we had a bad storm with high winds. I was not home at the time but the wind caught one of my windows (that swing out on a hinge) and ripped it off shattering the window. On my most recent utility bill my landlord asked that I pay for the damages to the windows. Do I have good reason to deny this request? If so whats the best way to do that? Can he claim that I was “negligent” in not locking my window? The cost is relatively insignificant ($150) but I dont feel in the wrong here. I also have renters insurance, is this something i should rather bill them for? Thanks!

Comment: One thing you should do in determining whether to submit an insurance claim is read the policy and understand what it covers and what the deductible is.  With regard to your landlord's claim, you should read your lease agreement, which should have something to say about liability for damage to the premises.

Comment: @phoog thanks for the insight! The lease states as far as liability goes is “the landlord shall be responsible for maintenance, repair, and replacement of rental property, unless the needed (etc etc etc) arises out of the tenants negligence or willful acts, whereupon it shall be the tenants responsibility (etc etc)